# Варианты взаимодействия Android приложения между двумя устройствами, без участия сервера

Tags: android, ios

Допустим приложение установлено на два устройства  Android и iOS. Оно взаимодействует через сервер, приложение с устройства1 посылает на сервер команду для устройства2,  устройство2 проверяет сервер находит сообщение что ей нужно выполнить команду и выполняет его. А какие есть варианты этого взаимодействия без участия сервера(в том плане что с участием, но не там где два устройства могут общаться без его)?

Я знаю что такое взаимодействие можно построить с помощью Push технологии. Когда  устройство1 посылает Push-сообщение  напрямую устройству2 минуя сервер, устройство2 ловит сообщение ресивиром и выполняет команду(Так ведь можно да?). А какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: Как вариант использовать BlueTooth взаимодействие

Comment: Не, надо по интернету.

Comment: Это не возможно, без сервера. Даже Push уведомления должны работать через сервер

Comment: Сервер сделает систему заметно надёжнее даже если использовать его только для установления соединения. Посмотрите на WebRTC, какие там с этим связаны проблемы.

Comment: Dynamic DNS в помощь

Comment: я так понимаю тэг ios по ошибке поставили

Comment: Нет, нужно чтоб между этими платформами тоже устройства общались.